# How to encode link http contain string "|"

Tags: java, android, json, http-post, urlencode

i have a problem in ANDROID
I have a ArrayList contains: TimeStart, TimeEnd
I want to Parse a link http to JSONArray. But my link http contain char "|".
Here are sample link: http://localhost/SilentTime.aspx?acc=abc&pass=123&username=test&timestart=10:56|12:41&timeend=10:59|13:41&order=set

I have a function read link http to JSON String, but it returns error.
Error at char "|". 
Error at line

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(linkHttp);
```

I use function  to encode link http

```
    URLEncoder.encode(linkHttp, "UTF-8");
```

It's jump Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at char "|"

How to encode char "|" ? What string i have to replace char "|" by? Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use its HTML-code or unicode number:

```
Unicode number: U+007C
HTML-code: &#124;
```

to avoid any problem linked to the  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: yeah, i done. I only replace char "|" by string "%7C". It's run OK.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Don't forget to validate the answer if it helped :)